# Metaphoric meaning of Hitchhiker’s?

Tags: meaning

There is a book named "Infinite Dimensional Analysis: A Hitchhiker’s Guide". I was wondering what "Hitchhiker’s" means as a metaphor in general?

Comment: I think the [publisher's description](http://www.amazon.com/Infinite-Dimensional-Analysis-Hitchhikers-Guide/dp/3540295860) answers this rather well: _[This book] is intended for the student or researcher who could benefit from functional analytic methods, but who does not have an extensive background in the subject and does not plan to make a career as a functional analyst_. In other words, it's a tongue-in-cheek way of saying it's perhaps not as in-depth as other related works – higher up the a "for Dummies" book, but still with more of a beginner's slant than other tomes might have.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I suspect that this is simply a reference to [The Hitchhiker's Guide to the Galaxy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Hitchhiker%27s_Guide_to_the_Galaxy/), a cult classic book which the target audience of this text is likely to understand.

The [Hitchhiker's Guide](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hitchhiker%27s_Guide_%28disambiguation%29) page informs us that there was a 1971 travel guide called *Hitch-hiker's Guide to Europe* and that other works since then which are some kind of "Hitchhiker's Guide" are likely inspired either by Douglas Adams' work, or by the original travel guide.

Comment: Thanks! Means easy to understand?

Comment: I think that "Hitchhiker's Guide" in the title of (what I take to be) a mathematics text is a kind of "geek handshake", and an indication that the content might be presented in some wacky or entertaining way.

Comment: @Tim, Kaz: Yes - if the title had been intended to imply "easy to understand", it would probably have been called the [*"Dummies Guide to](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22dummies+guide+to%22&oq=%22dummies+guide+to%22&aqs=chrome.0.57.34108642&sugexp=chrome,mod=18&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8) Infinite Dimensional Analysis"*.